# Eloquent hasManyThroughOne

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Laravel 4.1 introduced the hasManyThrough relationship. This assumes 2 relating hasMany relationships. I however would like to retrieve the hasMany relationships of a belongsTo relationship instead.

```
Project (id, contact_id, ...)
Contact (id, ...)
Address (id, contact_id, ...)
```

For each project, I would like to get all addresses.

I managed to do this using a belongsTo() relationship and some additional table joining. However, a belongsTo relationship binds a single object, instead of an array.

So my thoughts are I either need to:

1. ... be able to override the LIMIT 1 behavior on belongsTo relationships
2. ... or be able to override the hasManyThrough to work with a belongsTo as intermediate relationship.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are trying to set up a many-to-many relationship between Projects and Contacts, with a one-to-one relationship between Address and Contact. If that is the case you will need to create a pivot table "project_contact" with columns "project_id" and "contact_id" as well as any other columns (timestamps(), etc). Then you can set a "belongsToMany('Project')" relationship on the Contacts.

I'm not sure if that is what you're after, but it solves the problem as I understand it.

Comment: I have extremely simplified my question. Your answer would indeed suit my needs when this was all that I was trying to accomplish. Unfortunately I really need it this way, without adding an extra pivot table.

Comment: OK, so if I understand you correctly, you have a Project that has a single User, and each User has multiple Addresses. Is that correct?

Comment: You should be able to set up the Project -> Contact relationship using `public function contact() { return $this->belongsTo('Contact'); }` on the Projects model, then define the Addresses relationship using `public function addresses() { return $this->hasMany('Address'); }` on the Contacts model. Then if you load `$project = Project::find($id);` you can access the addresses as an array using `$project->contact->addresses`. To reduce this to 2 database queries using eager loading you would use `$project = Project::with('contact.addresses')->find($id);`.

Comment: That indeed is what I'm using now. However I have a fourth table, that makes things more complex; table Items(id, project_id, address_id, ...). My goal is to join the Items table with the Addresses table, whilst respecting the correct project_id. The problem is that the Address Model in this case does not know about the grandparent project_id, so I cannot write the right join.

Comment: Are you needing to relate Addresses to a Project when they are not related to the User? If you are just looking for a shortcut to $project->user->addresses, you could define that with `public function addresses() { return $this->hasManyThrough('Address, User'); }`, then you can access all related addresses using `$project->addresses` instead of `$project->user->addresses`. I may be misunderstanding the issue completely, and I apologize if that is the case.